# Maven not seeing the compiler on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

My Maven project isn't seeing the compiler -- which is JavaSE-1.8 on Eclipse. the compiler is running fine from everywhere else in Eclipse.

The error I keep getting is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project DNM: Compilation failure

[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>AxyMVN</groupId>
  <artifactId>DNM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>DNM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the configuration of the compiler on project seems fine:

- on the Project Explorer window, `JRE System Library` on the project shows that it is set to `JavaSE-1.8`.
- the `Java Compiler` properties for the project is set to `Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.8' on the Java Build Path`.
- in `Run Configurations` window of the project, the one that opens on `Right-click > Run as > Run configurations`, 
  the `JRE` tab show that it's set to `Workspace default JRE (jre1.8.0_20)`.

adding the following to the `<properties>` tag in `pom.xml` didn't change anything.

```
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

I didn't skip `Maven > Update Project` everytime I tried out the configuration.

the project isn't showing any other errors anywhere else.

What am I missing?

Note: I saw [Maven "build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5", even though I changed it to 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804945/maven-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-5-even-though-i-chang/31486040) among some other discussions.

Answer (score 1):

It is literally saying to you " Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?", which means - Don't run on jre but on jdk. download the jdk version and configure it, good luck

Answer (score 0):

`Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs.` fixed it. it was set to JRE-- set  it JDK-- the one my `JAVA_HOME` is showing.

[Eclipse/Maven error: "No compiler is provided in this environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099072/eclipse-maven-error-no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment?rq=1) helped it.