# Eclipse Maven and Java 8 problems

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8

I moved from simple web app to maven web app and with Eclipse Neon I encountered a frustrating problem: after I add in pom.xml the specification to use Java 8 or 7, it doesn't work.

To verify if it works I write a simple class where I use a try(expression) declaration.

What should I have to do to use Java 8 in maven (I have installed and it works in normal web app)?

The code of pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.webdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebParser</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>WebParser</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
          <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
          <version>2.23</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027255/eclipse-java-8-support)

Comment: I'm using eclipse Neon... I see that it is for Kepler?

Comment: java 8 is not supported by ur eclipse??? have you try it by code like lambda or List Set etc

Comment: I'm using latest version which it works only if I have Java 8

Comment: I know neon only run on java 8, have you set up java 8 or download java 8. do you set up your eclipse for java 8 by `project>properties>compiler`

Comment: Yes, this is the solution :) ... I found that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804945/maven-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-5-even-though-i-chang but you was faster like me to write :) ... thanks anyway for helping :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your `JAVA_HOME` must point to a JDK 1.8.
Else if is not the case,  you must specify a JDK 1.8 as source and target in the compiler configuration of your `pom.xml` in this way :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>      
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>D:\jdk1.8\bin\javac</executable>                
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, in eclipse, you must check in Preferences that :

- `Java->Installed JREs` has a 1.8 JRE/JDK installed.

You could set the following as default if you want to use the 1.8 for any new created projects in your Eclipse :

- `Java->Installed JREs` : select the 1.8.
- `Java->Compiler` : select the JDK compiler compliance level to 1.8.

If the default preferences don't use 1.8 compilation compliance and JDK/JRE or that the project was created outside from this Eclipse with preferences set to 1.8 compilation compliance and JDK/JRE, you should check and maybe adjust `properties` of your Eclipse project 
To do it, go in the properties of your project, then `Java Build Path` and in the `Libraries` tab. You must check that the `JRE System Library` uses Java 1.8. If it is not the case, remplace it with the 1.8 version. 
When it is done, always in the properties of your project, go to `Java Compiler` and check that you use JDK compiler compliance with Java 1.8.

It should work.

Answer (score 4):

It's funny :))

I searched 3-4 hours and I tried few methods and only after I asked here I found the solution :)

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> uncheck 'Use compilance from execution...' and choose '1.8'

Comment: And after maven update (Alt+F5) you have to change that setting again...

Answer (score 3):

In pom.xml, defined this `maven.compiler.source` properties to tell `Maven` to use `Java 8` to compile the project.

**Maven Properties Java 8**

```
<properties>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Compiler Plugin - Alternative, configure the plugin directly.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

as mentioned here -> [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Don't forget to update Maven project -> Alt + F5.